# bootstrap 4 css with ul and columns not working on safari

Tags: bootstrap-4, safari

I have a large list of checkboxes that I want to have arranged in 2 to 6 columns based on width of the container. Made a `<ul>` and it works perfect on Chrome and Firefox. Not on Safari.

There is a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x7oavbyn/)

CSS:

```
.configCheckboxes {
    column-count: 6;
    column-width: 7em;
}
```

HTML snippet from a bootstrap 4 card:

```
        <div class="card collapsed-card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="configCheckboxes">
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">A Label</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Another Label</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Short</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Medium</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">A Bit Longer</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Days</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Month</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Year</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Taxes</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Cats</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Dogs</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Horse</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Iguana</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Ducks</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Pig</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Elephant</label></li>
                <li><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">Tiger</label></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

On Safari I get check boxes in the 1st column but then it displays a bunch more rows of checkboxes below the 1st column of checkboxes, and the other columns have the `<li>` dot where there should be a checkbox. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7oavbyn/) and compare the Run results on Safari vs Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a fix. Add this:

```
.form-check-input{
  position: static;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
```

Now it works on Safari like on other browsers. Hope this helps someone.